# CSS how to set a image without set width and height

Tags: html, css

**my problem :**

I have the class `.logo` working perfecly with this size:  `width: 316px; height: 300px;`

the problem is this logo never will have this size always, the width and height should not be defined, so next logo can fits well.

I tried remove the **width and height** without no success, when I do this the logo does not appear.

it is something I can do in the css to make this work without set width and height?

https://jsfiddle.net/pLfgam3r/1/

```css
.logo {
  background-image: url('https://lh5.ggpht.com/tq3WqEUxtRyBn-d_0t3j6WKNHuJDrmLq-FE3GAYrsAMQFIaS7FIgRLfzzql2SvfvLqto=w300-rw');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 316px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.logo2 {
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfBR9aGrk9k/maxresdefault.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 316px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<div  class="logo2"></div>
```

Comment: you are using image as background-image, so obviously you need a container to set background. for that container you are suppose to set width and height when there is no content!

Comment: Your code is setting the height and width of the div, not the size of the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the background image show up without specific width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175195/why-doesnt-the-background-image-show-up-without-specific-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0):

Set `background-size: contain;`

https://jsfiddle.net/wuqvwpkL/1/

Answer (score 0):

I found this post:
[Why doesn't the background image show up without specific width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175195/why-doesnt-the-background-image-show-up-without-specific-width-and-height)

So your css should look like this:

```
.logo2 {
    background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfBR9aGrk9k/maxresdefault.jpg');
    no-repeat: true;
 display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 316px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

This is working for both logos that has different sizes.

https://jsfiddle.net/pLfgam3r/4/