# My background image isn't loading without a pixel value for height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to load an image as a background image as a responsive background image. but the image isn't loading. here is my CSS code.

```
.cover{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/cover.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the background image show up without specific width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175195/why-doesnt-the-background-image-show-up-without-specific-width-and-height)

Comment: Give it min-width, it will be fine. .cover { min-width: 10vw;}

Comment: @Robin i tried but didn't work

Comment: @LaljiTadhani i tred it already but couldn't find a clear solution. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `div` doesn't has content then its height will be `0px`,So the `background image` is not displayed. Try giving height as `350px` say or `100vh` . you can check the div height by giving `border`.Ref this [Why doesn't the background image show up without specific width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175195/why-doesnt-the-background-image-show-up-without-specific-width-and-height) for more details,hope it helps

Comment: The issue was div tag not having a value. I applied height as height: 100vh; and it worked fine. Thank you.