# Css background image doesn't display if height not set (why not adjusting automatically?)

Tags: html, css

I want to include background image which is oversized (4000px x 3000px) in the div,
in such a way that width will take max width of the screen and height will adjust to it.

I don't know why but it doesn't work if the height is not specified (like 1000px).
The image doesn't appear at all.

I wanted to make jsfiddle but there it works (probably because height is somehow specified automatically)

The part of code (HTML):

```
<section id="panels">
  <h1>PANELS</h1>
  <div class="section-img">
    <!-- here i want the image -->                 
  </div>
</section>
```

The part of code (CSS):

```
.section-img {
    background-size:     contain;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;    
    background-image: url("path/to/my/image");
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

And with this code nothing appears (as it looks the height is 0px), how can i do the thing that height will adjust to size of width i.e. scales itself.

Comment: Are you using any external styling options like bootstrap that might override your settings?

Comment: no, only my own css

Comment: Assuming you know image dimensions you can count height of image in percent of width and then specify padding-top for block in percents. Percents in padding are counted from width of element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Comment: Have you tried adding image as an element inside your div, and then giving it `z-index: -1` so it shows as a background, since your div is empty currently and it's auto height is 0

Comment: i didn't. But is it possible to write text on it later?

Comment: You will need to add position and z-index on both. Read more about z-index here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the background image show up without specific width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175195/why-doesnt-the-background-image-show-up-without-specific-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the div is inheriting the width of the parent `section` tag, taking into account any margin or padding on the body element. It has `display: block` so width is 100% , height is auto so it's the size of whatever inside. So in your case there's nothing inside the `div` tag, which means it's `height: auto;` value is `0`.

```css
.section-img {
    background-size:     contain;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;    
    background-image: url("https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg");
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; // auto means 0 if there's nothing in your div element
    display: block; // this is a default for every div tag
}
```

```html
<section id="panels">
  <h1>PANELS</h1>
  <div class="section-img">
    <!-- here i want the image -->                 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: but you just set the height to 100px. My image is bigger... I want the image width to scale down to screen size... and then height to scale automatically

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer `div` have no height, meaning it will take the height of whatever inside it. Without setting the height of your `div` class background image will not be displayed.

Comment: is it possible to create inside this div another div which will take height of the div with image and in that case it will have something inside so not 0 ?

Comment: nah, it doesn't work. I will try to use normal image in HTML and then do something with z-index

Answer (score 0):

Just try this replace the auto with 100% in height and check.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.section-img {
    background-size:     cover;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;    
    background-image: url(https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg);
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<section id="panels">
  <h1>PANELS</h1>
  <div class="section-img">
    <!-- here i want the image -->                 
  </div>
</section>
```

Are you like this .