# I can't make changing background image of my website to change

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

I am trying to make the background image of my website to change every certain quantity of seconds, I have tried to do this with this:

```js
var images = new Array(
  'Space.gif',
  'Windows.gif',

);

var slider = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bg-img')[0].setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("'+images[0]+'")');
  images.splice(images.length, 0, images[0]);
  images.splice(0, 1);
}, 10000);
```

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('space.gif'),background-image: url('windows.gif');">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

And I have also tried with this code of JavaScript:

```
 function changeBg(){

  const images = [
     'url("Space.gif")',
     'url("Windows.gif")',
    ]
    const selection = document.querySelector('selection')
    const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random()* images.length)];
    selection.style.backgroundImage = bg; 
}          
setInterval(changeBg, 1000000)
```

But nothing works :(

Comment: In your CSS, you are preparing the `<body>` for a background image. But your JavaScript references the `.bg-img` element. Do you want to apply the background image to the `<body>` or to the `<div>`? Also, if the `<div>` has no width or height, it likely won't show on the page.

Comment: I'm trying to change the background to the full page, so it means I will have to change in the css the "body" for "bg-img" right?

Comment: Why are you not able to fix the typo??

Comment: I could fix that typo of the missing quotations but my page still doesn't change the background image :/

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, you are preparing the `<body>` for a background image:

```
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

But you are adding the image to an element with the class "bg-img" rather than the `<body>`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bg-img')...
```

You can either (1) add the image to the `<body>` or (2) make the `<div>` cover the full screen:

**1) Set the image on the `<body>` element:**

> The [`Document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body) property represents the [`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) ... node of the current document, or `null` if no such element exists.

```js
var images = new Array(
  'https://fakeimg.pl/200x150/282868/eae0d0/',
  'https://fakeimg.pl/200x150/682828/eae0d0/'
);

var slider = setInterval(function() {
  document.body.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("' + images[0] + '")');
  images.splice(images.length, 0, images[0]);
  images.splice(0, 1);
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://fakeimg.pl/200x150/282828/eae0d0/');
}
```

**2) Or make the `<div>` full-screen:**

Since the `<div>` has [no content and no width or height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175195/why-doesnt-the-background-image-show-up-without-specific-width-and-height), it will not show on the page. You can  use CSS to make the element [cover the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window).

```js
var images = new Array(
  'https://fakeimg.pl/200x150/282868/eae0d0/',
  'https://fakeimg.pl/200x150/682828/eae0d0/'
);

var slider = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bg-img')[0].setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("' + images[0] + '")');
  images.splice(images.length, 0, images[0]);
  images.splice(0, 1);
}, 2000);
```

```css
.bg-img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://fakeimg.pl/200x150/282828/eae0d0/');
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```